# how to pass data from child component to state of parent component react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, state

PARENT

```
import Child from '../Child';

const Parent = () => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');

  const handleChild = (value) => {
    setInputValue(value);
    console.log('VALUE:', value);
    console.log('STATE:', inputValue);
  };
  console.log(inputValue); //shows the same as VALUE
  return (
    <View>
      <Child passInputValue={handleChild} />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Child

```
const Child = ({passInputValue}) => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState('');
  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput value={input} onChangeText={(text) => setInput(text)} />
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => passInputValue(input)}>
        <Text>SEND DATA TO PARENT</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};
```

When I fill the input and then press the button, the console shows me in VALUE: the current value of the input and in STATE the previous value of input

"CLICK 1"

VALUE:
'WHATEVER'

STATE:
''

"CLICK 2"

VALUE:
'WHATEVER'

STATE:
'WHATEVER'

what I need is that when I click, execute realm and save the value of inputValue, but it always saves the previous value

I would appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0):

change as follows

```
<Child passInputValue={(value)=>handleChild(value)} />
```

Comment: This isn't necessary since `handleChild` is already an arrow function.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is that React is executing the lines of `handleChild` asynchronously rather than in order.  You call `setInputValue(value)` to change the `inputValue`, but before the state gets updated `console.log('STATE:', inputValue)` has already begun executing with the previous value.  The update is happening correctly, but your log is printing the value before the update rather than after.

That's why you see the `console.log(inputValue)` statement which is *outside* of the function printing the correct value.  This function is run when the component re-renders, which happens *after* the state updates, so you are getting the updated value here.